# Android: show option menu after touching button for 3 or 4 second

Tags: android, contextmenu, android-menu

I want one option menu when I touch the button for 2 or 3 second in my application.
Example: In the Message Application when I touch particular message for 2 to 3 second then one option menu come which show:

Delete

copy

Lock

Forward

Copy to Sim

etc.
So how can I use this on my application.
Can I use

> onOptionsItemSelected

this method.Or something else.

Here One more thing which I want, suppose in Context Menu Five Action is there and after selecting fifth action first action will disable and only enable when I select Fourth Action.
Suppose the cose is:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Option Menu");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "First Action");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Second Action");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Third Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Fourth Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Fifth Action");
}
```

now when I select Fifth Action then First Action will disable and only enable when I select Fourth Action.
Please Suggest me...

Comment: Every thing works fine. Here one more thing I want. Which I mention above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, the menu which you are talking about is known as **Context Menu**, **not an Option Menu.**

More detailed example is given here: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/

Guidelines for Menu: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Once you are done with example, just implement [**`OnLongClickListener`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) to your button.

Comment: @vinitvikash God bless you...you should think twice before asking question.

Comment: Every thing works fine. Here one more thing I want. Which I mention above.

Comment: @vinitvikash this is not a proper way to ask question, you should be clear about your doubt.

Comment: @vinitvikash Please be clear when asking **the first time**. Every time you drastically change a question, you produce a page full of wrong answers. Please be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try LongClickListener for the button. It may suite your requirement.

```
 button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(
            ) {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //do the necessary here
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Every thing works fine. Here one more thing I want. Which I mention above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using context menu , this will be specific to the message and is easy as well. Its similar to options menu.

Comment: Every thing works fine. Here one more thing I want. Which I mention above.